# While loop adding unwanted line to file

Tags: python-3.x

The while loop adds the user input to the file as desired, but when I am done and hit <kbd>Q</kbd> to stop, instead of just stopping the while loop, a `q` gets concatenated and written to the file, which is not desired.

How do I quit the script without writing/concatenating `q` ?

```
def regular_host():
    host = ''
    while host !='q':
        host = input('Enter host >')
        stuff = (f'add host name h-{host}-g ip-address {host}\n')
        print(stuff)
        with open('file.txt', 'a') as f:
            f.write(stuff)
```

File contents after running the script:

```
add host name h-192.168.1.1-g ip-address 192.168.1.1
add host name h-q-g ip-address q
```

Expected results:

```
add host name h-192.168.1.1-g ip-address 192.168.1.1
```

Actual results:

```
add host name h-192.168.1.1-g ip-address 192.168.1.1
add host name h-q-g ip-address q
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The unwanted line is added since when the user presses `q` the block of code inside while loop runs for one last time and the loop is terminated since `host == 'q'`. A simple modification in the code just below should solve the issue.

```
def regular_host():
host = ''
while host !='q':
    host = input('Enter host >')
    if host == 'q':
        break
    stuff = (f'add host name h-{host}-g ip-address {host}\n')
    print(stuff)
    with open('file.txt', 'a') as f:
        f.write(stuff)
```